# Fastclick interfering with jQuery mobile non-native selects

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using Fastclick with jQuery Mobile and it's all working fine apart from some non-native selects now require two taps (not a double tap) to activate.

I'm adding the 'needsclick' class to all elements of the select, prior to attaching Fastclick, in an attempt to get Fastclick to ignore the selects:

```
        $("div.ui-select").addClass("needsclick");
        $("#searchPanel .ui-btn-inner").addClass("needsclick");
        $("#searchPanel a").addClass("needsclick");
        $("#searchPanel select").addClass("needsclick");
        bindFastClick();
```

This has the desired effect in the markup, blitzing the whole thing with 'needsclick':

```
<div id="searchPanel">
.....

<a href="#" role="button" id="searchLocationSlct-button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="searchLocationSlct-menu" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" class="ui-btn ui-mini ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-right needsclick ui-btn-up-c">
     <span class="ui-btn-inner needsclick">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">
             <span class="needsclick">Location</span>
        </span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
</a>
<select name="searchLocationSlct" class="needsclick" id="searchLocationSlct" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false" data-native-menu="false" tabindex="-1">
    <option value="Camber Sands"> - Camber Sands</option>
    <option value="Romney Sands"> - Romney Sands</option>
    <option value="Shurland Dale"> - Shurland Dale</option>
</select>
```

But still I need two taps (not a double tap) to activate the select. If I turn off Fastclick, a single tap activates the non-native select, as expected.

I've googled for this problem, but can't find anything. Anyone seen this before or got any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that when you add class="needsclick" to a non-native select, like this:

```
<select name="searchPriceto" id="searchPriceto" data-native-menu="false" class="needsclick">
<option value="">Price to</option>
...
```

then the class 'needsclick' appears rendered in the real select (which is positioned off-screen, hidden away) and in the label text only for the fake select button:

```
<span class="needsclick">Price to</span>
```

If your big fat thumb happens to click the text exactly then your non-native menu appears first time, as desired. But if you miss the text and hit the button span, or the parent anchor, or any other parent element then nothing happens, until you try again (for reasons I'm not entirely clear about).

I fixed this by adding 'needsclick' to all the elements in the nest, prior to binding Fastclick like so:

```
        $("#searchPanel .ui-btn-inner").addClass("needsclick");
        $("#searchPanel .ui-btn-text").addClass("needsclick");
        $("#searchPanel a").addClass("needsclick");
        $("#searchPanel select").addClass("needsclick");
```

as well as having class='needsclick' in the original select tag markup as shown above.

In my original question I was barking up the right tree, but I'd missed one of the elements in the heirarchy (#searchPanel .ui-btn-text) and it seems that this was preventing the fix from working.

I can't help feeling there's a better way than this as it feels a bit hacky, but I thought I'd share it with anyone that has the same problem.

It'd be nice if one could apply Fastclick to only identified elements using a jquery selector :)

Comment: Regarding your last sentence:
`$('#element1,.elements2,.elements3').each(function() { new FastClick(this); });`

Comment: @Adam Excellent I'll give it a go! I did look into this briefly but I couldn't find any evidence of it being possible.

Comment: You just have to make sure that, using the above code as an example, `.elements2` aren't nested in `#element1`, for example, because in that case you would be applying `FastClick` twice. I use the code I posted on a mobile web app and it works fine.